# nuxt-Gmap multiple infowindow

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js

Can anyone help me how to close an info window if user click another marker..
In google documentation you open infowindows yourself but in nuxt-gmap iyts like,

```
                 <GMap :key="mapRender"
                    ref="gMap"
                    language="en"
                    :center="{lat: 36.266114, lng: 29.413674}"
                    :options="{mapTypeControl: false, zoomControl:true, scrollwheel:true,
                    scaleControl:false, fullscreenControl:false, styles: mapStyle}"
                    :zoom="12"
                    >
                    <!-- :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}" -->
                    <GMapMarker
                        v-for="location in locations" :key="location"
                    >
                        <GMapInfoWindow>
                        <code>
                            <div>
                                info
                            </div>
                        </code>
                        </GMapInfoWindow>
                    </GMapMarker>
                    <GMapCircle :options="circleOptions"/>
                </GMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is nuxt-gmap true SSR? If it isn't you could use [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps)

I'm using this package on my nuxt project it works like a charm.
Maybe my implementation inspires your point of view.

```
<GmapMap
  :center="{lat: xx.xxx, lng: xxx.xxx}"
  :zoom="13"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 100%; height: 870px;"
>
  <GmapMarker
    :key="i"
    v-for="(branch, i) in branches"
    :position="{lat: branch.lat, lng: branch.lng}"
    clickable
    @click="selectedBranch = branch"
  />
  <gmap-info-window
    :position="selectedBranchPosition"
    :opened="!!selectedBranch.id"
    @closeclick="selectedBranch = {}"
  >
    {{ selectedBranch }}
  </gmap-info-window>
</GmapMap>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      selectedBranch: {},
      branches: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedBranchPosition() {
      if (!this.selectedBranch.id) { return null; }
      return { lat: this.selectedBranch.lat, lng: this.selectedBranch.lng };
    },
  }
```